# How do you configure ECS to allow access to Kinesis Stream

Tags: docker, .net-core, amazon-ecs, amazon-kinesis

I have a socket server, written in c# (.net core) that receives data from devices over a TCP connection. I am then deploying this to Amazon ECS.

Initially, I was queuing the received data using Amazon SQS, but I have reworked my application to use Kinesis streams.

If I run the .net core application on my development machine, everything is fine. If I run it in a docker container locally, it also runs correctly. The problem is when I deploy as an ECS task, when I get the following error on the Kinesis SDK call to PutRecords:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such device or address ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such device or address
```

The security group shows that I have no outgoing rules that might be blocking access to Kinesis. I initially thought I might need to add something to the dockerfile, but local testing suggests that this isn't the problem either.

I have checked and rechecked that the Kinesis endpoint is correct, so I'm not sure what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you share your ECS permission role ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will do when back at my desk. I don't suspect the role though because I am using cloudformation to generate both a role and an IAM user with identical policies attached. I am using the keys of the IAM user for local testing without problems, so the role should perform the same.

Comment: I have done similar thing, but it's with Java + Python KCL. Do you think that it's related to client code ?

Comment: Currently, I'm looking at spinning up the application in docker running on linux. My dev machine is running windows, so I wonder if there is a difference in behaviour between the operating systems (I have seen differences in the past)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake in the end. I had different setup mechanisms for initialising the `AmazonKinesisClient` depending if the client was running in the cloud (Using the IAM role) or running away from it on a server (Using the IAM user).

The cloud initialisation was trying to determine the AWS region from the Kinesis stream name, which it couldn't do and hence future calls failed.